# How to get the parent of specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quick note: I am quite noob regarding jQuery, so sorry if something might seem like a monstrosity :D

Hi everyone, I have a problem with a jQuery function using .parent() that I have to fix.

I want to target a particular  instead of the closest one with the .parent() function in order to change the color of that specific div.

I have explained everything in this imgur collection of images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOaZN.jpg

How can I do it? In the collection there should be everything about the function and what it affects, but if you need my entire .rar of the project let me know and I can upload it and give it to you, so maybe you can test it.

If you want my .rar, keep in mind though that this is for a group project and I don't want to mix stuff around too much because it was not done only by me. I'd rather try and keep everything as it is right now except the notes.append() part and the function regarding the color change.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stackoverflow users won't ask to give them your code by .rar, review your code and read through many lines of **unrelated** code just to find out a problem in a single line of elementary jQuery code. Make sure to write your question in such way that anybody can understand your problem, not only you. Good luck :)

Comment: The detail in your imgur link is great, but you should definitely be including applicable code in the question as text, and, as @YeldarKurmangaliyev points out, provide an isolated example of the issue.

Comment: Can you try to break it down to the specific problem you are having, maybe create a simple example

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev what if the whole .rar would revolve just around that page/those notes?

Everything I have in the JS file is:

- button to create a new note (which is needed)
- function that attaches a close button to the note, not needed
- functions that are used to save and load notes on page change (the button to create a new note is on page 1, the notes are on page 2), which I guess are needed as well

Answer (score 0):

the div you want to target in your code has an id=test, so just do `$("#test")` to get it.

alternatively if you want to traverse up the tree, use `.parents()` instead of `.parent()`. i.e.`$(this).parents("#test")`

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

> This method is similar to .parents(), except .parent() only travels a
>   single level up the DOM tree.

Comment: Hi, 

I have tried to change the line `var target = $(this).parent();` with:

`var target = $(this).parents('#test');`
`var target = $('test');`
`var target = $(this).parents('test');`

Nothing worked.

Comment: `var target = $('test');` / parents('test'). this looks for an element called 'test' (<test></test>). that's not what you need.

Comment: I have tried to change the '' with the "", but this time as well nothing happens

Comment: `var target = $(this).parents('#test');` would be the key. alternatively you could do `var target = $(this).parent().parent().parent()`. but first make sure what doesn't work exactly. might be you are getting the element, but what you want todo with it creates another problem. `console.log(target);` for instance to see if it is found

Comment: quote's don't matter in this case

Comment: I have tried all the possibilities and those are the results:

http://imgur.com/a/8310c

It has some problems in getting the <div>, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Look into the .parents jQuery method.

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

**Long answer**:  I made an example to help illustrate how to use .parents()

Here's a great example on how to understand relative selectors in jQuery.  I use the .find function which finds a child that suits the requirements (img).  I also use .parents that search all parent elements for something that satisfies the restrictions.

```js
$(".container").find("img").click(function () {
 $(this).parents(".super-container").css("background","blue");
});
```

```css
div {
 padding: 30px;
 margin: 30px;
}

.super-container {
 background:red;
}

.container {
 background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="super-container">
 <div class="container">
  <img src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Xen-Panda-Test_Day-125px.png" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()`

For example: `$(this).closest('div.someNote-box').css('background-color','red');`

See the reference here: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the closest() function but it did not work, it did not change the color of either the background of the note OR the background of the popup